# a function to copy an array that could effect the original array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Just a thought experiment
.. no use case

concat docs

> Note: Concatenating array(s)/value(s) will leave the originals untouched. **Furthermore, any operation on the new array will have no effect on the original arrays, and vice versa.**

Is there a function to make a copy an array that **could** have an effect on the  original arrays, and vice versa?

example:

```
var data = [1,2,3]
var copyData = makeCopy(data);
```

if data changes so does copyData and vice versa.

what would be a practical use case for this?

Comment: "Is there a function to make a copy an array that could have an effect on the original arrays": No. Practical use case to pass by reference instead of a copy? It comes down to each use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you make a *copy* on an array, it won't ever affect the original array.

However, this doesn't apply to what the array points to, which may be objects.

Comment: could you explain more about "what the array points to?"  and why does it matter if it points to an "object"?  i'm kind of a nerb with javascript.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood An object's value is a reference to it, or a pointer, like in C. So if you had two arrays that both had a reference to the same object, modifying it via its reference in one will mean the second reference (which points to the same thing) will also *see* that change.